# How to add sub menu items in contextmenustrip using C#4.0?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, contextmenustrip

I have one contextmenustrip control associated with treenode. I have created one menu item in contextmenustrip manually in the form itself(for example named as "Assign").

Now I want to add sub menu items whenever user clicks this Assign item, it will create a list of users name as a sub menu item with checked or unchecked option.

For example, once user clicked Assign then I want to show the user name dynamically.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

To add an item, you would call

```
myContextMenuStrip.Items.Add("Item title", null, myClickHandler);
```

To add a sub-menu, you take an existing item and do the same to it:

```
(myContextMenuStrip.Items[0] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Add(...)
```

Answer (score 30):

Define your menu strip and items

```
ContextMenuStrip menu = new ContextMenuStrip();
ToolStripMenuItem item, submenu;
```

Create new item.

```
submenu = new ToolStripMenuItem();
submenu.Text = "Sub-menu 1";
```

At this time your new item is just like others.
Now create several new items and add them to submenu:

```
item = new ToolStripMenuItem();
item.Text = "Sub-item 1";
submenu.DropDownItems.Add(item);

item = new ToolStripMenuItem();
item.Text = "Sub-item 2";
submenu.DropDownItems.Add(item);
```

At last add sub-menu to your main ContextMenuStrip

```
menu.Items.Add(submenu);
```

Comment: Thank you Kamarado, the breakdown helped a lot!